# ASP.NET Chart not showing in Web Farm Env

Tags: asp.net, session, charts, controls, web-farm

We are using Microsoft's charting control built-in ASP.NET 3.5 but Chart image sometimes doesn't come up. Instead, it shows a broken Image icon.

We are using SQL Server for session and we have 2 server's web farm. We found a suggestion on one of the forums to use STORAGE=SESSION in a web farm environment but that doesn't work either.

This is the entry we have in web.config file.

`<ADD KEY="CHARTIMAGEHANDLER" VALUE="STORAGE=SESSION;TIMEOUT=20;" />`

Can anyone suggest why the CHART control doesn't work in Web Farm Environment.

Answer (score 2):

While this is old, I did just have the problem as well, and following information in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deliant/archive/2008/12/02/managing-chart-generated-images-with-chart-image-handler.aspx (but, note, we are using Framework 4.5), then changing the web config from

```
 add key="ChartImageHandler"   value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=C:\inetpub\temp\ImageFiles\;"
```

to
    add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=session;timeout=20"/

worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made this setting?

```
MyChart.ImageStorageMode = ImageStorageMode.UseHttpHandler;
```

Comment: No, that is only supported in .NET 4.0. We are using 3.5